# Vue CLI 3 doesn't create .vuerc file

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm using Vue CLI 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 to create some test projects. As per the [doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config), I should have a `.vuerc` file created in my Home directory. However, when I run:

```
vue create test-project
```

no such file is created. Projects work fine but running `vue config` gives the following error:

> lundincast@lundincast:~/Vuejs-projects/test-app$ vue config
>   ERROR 
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open /home/lundincast/.vuerc > Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open '/home/lundincast/.vuerc'

I've tried with several option (saving preset or not, etc...) to no avail. Why isn't that config file created?

Comment: .vuerc is only created when you select to save your options as the new defaults.

Answer (score 1):

.vuerc files are only created after you have asked vue cli to save a preset for you at the end of the vue create process prompts

The file is stored in your user directory and can be edited with vue config --edit

Comment: Thanks! FYI, your .vuerc file is probably in your OS user root directory. For instance, my .vuerc file on Windows is at C:\Users\mcgee\.vuerc -- this is helpful in order to manually set the package manager to use in @vue/cli, because interface doesn't let you change the package manager once set (and PNPM has trouble installing currently, so I needed to change to "packageManager": "npm" in the .vuerc file.

Answer (score 0):

After running:

```
vue create hello-world
```

.vuerc file will be created in your user root diretory